# Windows Phone after splash screen storyboard animation delegate touch events to webview

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();             

           PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("SplashScreen.png", UriKind.Relative);
                    StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
                    BitmapImage sImage = new BitmapImage();
                    sImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                    sImage.SetSource(resourceInfo.Stream);
                    Image splashImage = new Image();
                    splashImage.Source = sImage;                                           
                    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(splashImage);
                    OnImageOpened(splashImage, null);                        
                    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Activated"));
                };
        }

        private void OnImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                To = 0,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)
            };

            Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, (DependencyObject)sender);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);              
            storyboard.Begin();
        }


    }
```

This is my splash image. CordovaView is custom webview

```
<Image x:Name="splashImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="SplashScreen.png" ImageOpened="OnImageOpened"></Image>
<my:CordovaView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                   x:Name="CordovaView"   
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Background="Transparent"
                   StartPageUri="/www/default/index.html"                   
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Above is my code . When i start the app splash screen is displayed and fadesout. I will be touch on HTML page buttons on webview

When i press power button, display is turned off and phone goes in stand by mode(not switched off) and when i turn it on and unlock the screen , splash screen is displayed and fades out successfully and my webview is displayed. But when i touch my html buttons on webview no action is happening. How to route the events to webview?

Comment: can you please format your code. I don't think your problem has anything to do with the using statements or the commented out code. Please remove it to make this more readable

Comment: i have removed the commented codes...